# Authenticating with dovecot

Tags: dovecot

I'm trying to access my emails using thunderbird but I'm getting an auth problem. I'm using valid certs and did `adduser testuser` with a simple password (1 letter, 8 didn't seem to change anything).

According to the logs it can't find the user. I haven't modified 10-auth.conf or anything in conf.d do I need to? Here is my dovecot.conf and log file

```
disable_plaintext_auth = no
mail_privileged_group = mail
mail_location = mbox:~/mail:INBOX=/var/mail/%u
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}

passdb {
  driver = shadow
  args = blocking=no
}

protocols = " imap"

service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
  }
}
ssl=required
ssl_cert = </etc/letsencrypt/live/MY_DOMAIN.COM/fullchain.pem
ssl_key = </etc/letsencrypt/live/MY_DOMAIN.COM/privkey.pem

auth_verbose=yes
auth_debug=yes
auth_debug_passwords=yes
mail_debug=yes
```

Log file

```
dovecot: master: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1 uid=0 code=kill)
dovecot: anvil: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1 uid=0 code=kill)
dovecot: log: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1 uid=0 code=kill)
dovecot: master: Dovecot v2.2.13 starting up for imap (core dumps disabled)
dovecot: auth: Debug: Loading modules from directory: /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/auth
dovecot: auth: Debug: Read auth token secret from /var/run/dovecot/auth-token-secret.dat
dovecot: auth: Debug: auth client connected (pid=5293)
dovecot: auth: Debug: client in: AUTH#0111#011PLAIN#011service=imap#011secured#011session=dtEqfrs9fwBo3ndE#011lip=1.2.3.4#011rip=123.123.123.123#011lport=143#011rport=6527
dovecot: auth: Debug: client passdb out: CONT#0111
dovecot: auth: Debug: client in: CONT#0111#011AHRlc3R1c2VyAHA= (previous base64 data may contain sensitive data)
dovecot: auth: Debug: shadow(testuser,123.123.123.123,<dtEqfrs9fwBo3ndE>): lookup
dovecot: auth: shadow(testuser,123.123.123.123,<dtEqfrs9fwBo3ndE>): unknown user
dovecot: auth: Debug: client passdb out: FAIL#0111#011user=testuser
dovecot: auth: Debug: client in: AUTH#0112#011PLAIN#011service=imap#011secured#011session=dtEqfrs9fwBo3ndE#011lip=1.2.3.4#011rip=123.123.123.123#011lport=143#011rport=6527#011resp=AHRlc3R1c2VyAHA= (previous base64 data may contain sensitive data)
dovecot: auth: Debug: shadow(testuser,123.123.123.123,<dtEqfrs9fwBo3ndE>): lookup
dovecot: auth: shadow(testuser,123.123.123.123,<dtEqfrs9fwBo3ndE>): unknown user
dovecot: auth: Debug: client passdb out: FAIL#0112#011user=testuser
dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (auth failed, 2 attempts in 8 secs): user=<testuser>, method=PLAIN, rip=123.123.123.123, lip=1.2.3.4, TLS, session=<dtEqfrs9fwBo3ndE>
dovecot: auth: Debug: auth client connected (pid=5296)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all likelihood, you want to be using the [pam password database](http://wiki.dovecot.org/PasswordDatabase/PAM), not the [shadow password database](http://wiki.dovecot.org/PasswordDatabase/Shadow). But if you're going to use the shadow database, you need to either disable the auth-worker processes (by adding `args = blocking=no` to the `passdb` section) or have the auth-workers run as group `shadow`:

```
service auth-worker {
  group = shadow
}
```

Both of those solutions come from the wiki. Another good solution is not to use system passwords and instead use, e.g., the [passwd-file database](http://wiki.dovecot.org/AuthDatabase/PasswdFile). Example with passwd-file:

```
passdb {
  driver = passwd-file
  args = scheme=SHA512-CRYPT username_format=%u /etc/dovecot/passwords

}
```

then for your example user "testuser" with password of "p", `/etc/dovecot/passwords` would look like:

```
testuser:{SHA512-CRYPT}$6$R6MuJ818vCtvNw1y$ALycf9nfP8mL7EZysLTZJlnNGuygRHhr9xCDFi8tlIHND4i6fI8wwY6t0dAL6rOY0Jat2iZmQgqz4vEFT/0fa1
```

That huge hash value can be obtained via `doveadm pw -s SHA512-CRYPT` (it will be different each time, due to salting).

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood but here are the results http://pastebin.com/kSwWBPhF as a test i set my password to `p` (log says `x` for some reason). Am I to used a different type of passwd file?

Comment: passwd-file has a different format than /etc/passwd; I'll add in an example.

Comment: @acidzombie24 example added.

Comment: Thanks. I had to add the user uid/gid so I put this after the password in the password file i made `user:{sha...}.../1234:1003:1003` and I had to change `mail_location = mbox:/var/mailout/%u:...` bc the default (I think it was `~/mail`) wouldn't work. Everything appears to be fine